# How to plot random intercept and slope in a mixed model with multiple predictors?

Tags: r, plot, mixed-models, lmer, random-effects

Is it possible to plot the random intercept or slope of a mixed model when it has more than one predictor?

With one predictor I would do like this:

```
#generate one response, two predictors and one factor (random effect)
resp<-runif(100,1, 100)
pred1<-c(resp[1:50]+rnorm(50, -10, 10),resp[1:50]+rnorm(50, 20, 5))
pred2<-resp+rnorm(100, -10, 10)
RF1<-gl(2, 50)

#gamm
library(mgcv)
mod<-gamm(resp ~ pred1, random=list(RF1=~1))
plot(pred1, resp, type="n")
for (i in ranef(mod$lme)[[1]]) {
abline(fixef(mod$lme)[1]+i, fixef(mod$lme)[2])
}

#lmer
library(lme4)
mod<-lmer(resp ~ pred1 + (1|RF1))
plot(pred1, resp, type="n")
for (i in ranef(mod)[[1]][,1]) {
abline(fixef(mod)[1]+i, fixef(mod)[2])
}
```

But what if I have a model like this instead?:

```
mod<-gamm(resp ~ pred1 + pred2, random=list(RF1=~1))
```

Or with lmer

```
mod<-lmer(resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + (1|RF1))
```

Should I consider all the coefficients or only the ones of the variable that I'm plotting?

Thanks

Comment: Basically, you have to decide what you want to do about the other variables.  The most common procedure is to pick a reference value for one variable (e.g. `pred2` equal to its mean) and plot the slope with respect to `pred1` for that value.  Or you could pick several values of `pred2` and plot a (set of) lines for each one, possibly in separate subplots, or (ugliest) do 3D plots and plot planes `resp~f(pred1,pred2)` instead.

Comment: Thank you Ben, Sorry but I'm not sure to follow you, what do you mean exactly for "pick a reference value for one variable"? How would you do it in practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
## generate one response, two predictors and one factor (random effect)
set.seed(101)
resp <- runif(100,1,100)
pred1<- rnorm(100, 
           mean=rep(resp[1:50],2)+rep(c(-10,20),each=50),
           sd=rep(c(10,5),each=50))
pred2<- rnorm(100, resp-10, 10)
```

**NOTE** that you should probably **not** be trying to fit a random
effect for an grouping variable with only two levels -- this will
almost invariably result in an estimated random-effect variance of zero,
which will in turn put your predicted lines right on top of each
other -- I'm switching from `gl(2,50)` to `gl(10,10)` ...

```
RF1<-gl(10,10)
d <- data.frame(resp,pred1,pred2,RF1)

#lmer
library(lme4)
mod <- lmer(resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + (1|RF1),data=d)
```

The development version of `lme4` has a `predict()` function
that makes this a little easier ...

- Predict for a range of `pred1` with `pred2` equal to its mean,
  and vice versa.  This is all a little bit cleverer than it needs
  to be, since it generates all the values for both focal predictors
  and plots them with ggplot in one go ...

()

```
nd <- with(d,
           rbind(data.frame(expand.grid(RF1=levels(RF1),
                      pred1=seq(min(pred1),max(pred1),length=51)),
                      pred2=mean(pred2),focus="pred1"),
                 data.frame(expand.grid(RF1=levels(RF1),
                      pred2=seq(min(pred2),max(pred2),length=51)),
                      pred1=mean(pred1),focus="pred2")))
nd$val <- with(nd,pred1[focus=="pred1"],pred2[focus=="pred2"])
pframe <- data.frame(nd,resp=predict(mod,newdata=nd))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pframe,aes(x=val,y=resp,colour=RF1))+geom_line()+
         facet_wrap(~focus,scale="free")
```

- Alternatively, focusing just on `pred1` and generating predictions for a (small/discrete) range of `pred2` values ...

()

```
nd <- with(d,
           data.frame(expand.grid(RF1=levels(RF1),
                      pred1=seq(min(pred1),max(pred1),length=51),
                      pred2=seq(-20,100,by=40))))
pframe <- data.frame(nd,resp=predict(mod,newdata=nd))
ggplot(pframe,aes(x=pred1,y=resp,colour=RF1))+geom_line()+
         facet_wrap(~pred2,nrow=1)
```

You might want to set `scale="free"` in the last `facet_wrap()` ... or
use `facet_grid(~pred2,labeller=label_both)`

For presentation you might want to replace the `colour` aesthetic,
with `group`, if all you want to do is distinguish among groups
(i.e. plot separate lines) rather than identify them ...